# Storing pixel based world data

Tags: 2d, pixel, terrain, destruction

I am making a 2d game with destructable terrain. It will be on iOS but I am looking for ideas or pseudocode, not actual code. I'm wondering how to store a large amount of data. (It will be a large world, approximately 64000 pixels wide and 9600 tall. Each pixel needs a way to store what type of object it is.) I was hoping to use a 2D array but a quick load test showed that this is not feasable (even using a 640x480 grid I dropped below 1 fps)
I also tried the method detailed here: http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=315851 (I used to use Game Maker and remembered this method) however is seems a bit cumbersome and recombining the objects again is nearly impossible.
So what other methods are there? Does anyone know how Worms worked? What about image editors, how do they store the colour of each pixel?
Thankyou,
YM

Comment: How many *types* of objects are you going to need if you're just storing individual pixels? Pixels should not be objects.

Comment: Well I will need dirt, rock and mineral deposits, as well as some other materials. I was hoping to avoid each pixel being an object, possibly having instead an array of integers, each number corresponding to a material type. The rendering engine would look-up each pixel and draw the correct material on.

Comment: A pixel? Why not use blocks of say 8x8 pixels (or whatever) to represent objects or parts of large objects? Your world map/array will then be much smaller, hence faster to search and render (fewer look-ups per pixel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am most likely going to use Polygon based storage.

Answer (score 0):

[Run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) can help with your memory issues

Comment: Yeah, but what I was really looking for was a better way. I'm probably going to use Polygons instead of Pixels (Vector vs Raster) and that should be faster AND use less memory. Thanks anyway, not really answering the question though.